# get the bounding box of a D3 graph

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I am generating a graph (tree) using the D3 tree layout.

I would like to adjust the size and view box of the SVG depending of the final size of the diagram.

How can I get the bounding box (min x and y and max x and y) of the generated graph?

code I am using is from http://zubasoft.at/2015/05/organigramm-mittels-d3-js-realisieren/

Comment: Can you share some code? Did you look at `getBBox()`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Code added. Can we use getBBox() on a set (group) of elements?

Comment: It should work on an svg `<g>`

Comment: I will test this tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
var svgBbox = _svg.select("g").getBBox();
var h = svgBbox.height;
var w = svgBbox.width;
```

Comment: I tried to add an overlay rect showing the bounding box but even if the height is correct, the width and x are bot incorrect. What can cause an incorrect bounding box?

Comment: `What can cause an incorrect bounding box?` Perhaps you are adding or removing elements, or making transformations *after* you are calculating your bounding box values.

Comment: Yes, I've ended up to calculate this bounding box by myself. Thanks for your help.